# Auto Routing Bundle - and parameters? (Symfony CMF)

Tags: php, symfony-cmf

I was successful with getting Symfony CMF and Auto Routing Bundle (and a custom contoller) to load documents in the following manner (path):

```
.../category/article-name
```

This works fine. But I need something like this, easily achieved by standard Symfony2:

```
.../category/article-name/{page}
```

Where page is passed to a controller as a parameter,
eg. $page = 2 -> controller processes content of the Article document to display only given page
or $page = null -> (so no {page} parameter at all) - as above, but displayed is page default that is 1

**How to make routing-auto bundle of the Symfony CMF to use parameters in routes?**

So that the basic path is exactly as it is configured as in this Auto Routing Bundle configuration, but additionally I can use parameters passed to a controller, so that additional decisions can be made upon them. Any hints? Thanks!

My config for auto routing:

```
    MyApp\MyCmsBundle\Document\Article:
        content_path:
            #fixed path of all categories and therefore articles
            articles_categories_path:
                provider: [specified, { path: /cms/routes }]
                exists_action: use
                not_exists_action: throw_exception
            #category path
            category_path:
                provider: [content_method, { method: getRouteNodeCategory }]
                exists_action: use
                not_exists_action: throw_exception
        #article name
        content_name:
            provider: [content_method, { method: getTitle }]
            exists_action: [auto_increment, { pattern: -%d }]
            not_exists_action: create
    MyApp\MyCmsBundle\Document\ArticlesCategory:
        content_path:
            #fixed path of all categories and therefore articles
            articles_categories_path:
                provider: [specified, { path: /cms/routes }]
                exists_action: use
                not_exists_action: throw_exception
        #category name
        content_name:
            provider: [content_method, { method: getTitle }]
            exists_action: use
            not_exists_action: create
```

getRouteNodeCategory() of the Article Document just returns a parents (i.e. category) name. Here's part of this document content:

```
public function getRouteNodeCategory()
{
    return $this->parent->getTitle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible in the RoutingAutoBundle but it could be easily implemented.

The RoutingAutoBundle creates Route documents which extend the CMF's Route object. These Route objects do support *variable patterns* which allow you to specify dynamic paramters:

https://github.com/symfony-cmf/RoutingBundle/blob/1.2/Model/Route.php#L53

So we would just need to extend the mapping to include details on dynamic (variable) parameters in the URL.

Note also that the a new version of the routing auto bundle will soon be released which features a much better configuration format.

If you could create an issue detailing your use case, we will try and implement it for the 1.0 release.

Comment: Thanks! Here's opened request: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/RoutingAutoBundle/issues/110